# "An org admin has to sign the addendum before you can select the options Apps or Apps and web" | Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I want to access my firebase through google analytics. But I have problem when creating property in Google Analytics. To be Information I using same account (gmail) for both of them. Here what google analytics said
[image: An org admin has to sign the addendum before you can select the options Apps pr Apps and web]
Please can someone explain to me what does it means and what should i do, i have been surfing through search engine but did'nt get the result.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's support, it should be available in the Google Marketing Platform interface under organization settings. I cannot find it from there either.

EDIT: The Google sales partner needs to accept the addendum. Also, it's not available on the client's account, where you want to use the property, but on the sales partner's account.